# How to change the z-index of the display:inline-block element?

Tags: css

I'm trying to mimic the coverflow UI here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqWMb/)

As you can see on the right, the last image is covering the second last image. How do i circumvent this problem, or is there a better method other than *display:inline-block*. I'm trying to avoid using *position:absolute* as this involve calculating the position for every single image.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/qqWMb/1/

```
li:nth-last-child(2) {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1
}
```

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthlastchild

Comment: `position: relative;` worked like charm. Thanks a lot.